# Programmatically using alternative resource files?

Tags: android, resources

Is there any way to programmatically select an alternative resource file to use in the app? I have a selection of buttons in my app, and want to use a different set whenever my app is in a certain mode.

Is there any way to achieve this other than manually setting the image resource on every image in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a layout filled with exactly the views you want and inflate that at any time. Though maybe I'm not understanding your question... do you wish for R.drawable.myImage to point to 2 different things? The answer to that is no, that's not possible, but it seems like it would be pretty easy to get around this need by creating two (or more) "pointer" arrays that can point to whatever resources you want, and set those as the src for your images.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to set a flag and have Android take care of everything for me using R.drawable.myImage :( Ah well

Comment: well, the solution I propose (which wannik has actually described in code) is just about as "flaggy" as I can imagine :)

Comment: Not easily implemented in xml unfortunately. I still need to programmically set the required bitmap. I guess I could make a custom button that handles this for me

Answer (score 1):

Declare a two-dimensional array to store the resource constant.

```
int[][] sets { {R.id.a, R.id.b, R.id.c}, {R.id.d, R.id.e, R.id.f}};
```

You can choose the set of views by changing the first index of the array `set`.